# Rails 4, Ancestry gem, Botstrap Dropdown menu. Too many queries. Optimize query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, ancestry

I want a dropdown vertical menu for my Rails 4 + ancestry gem.

I found this: http://www.bootply.com/uBoT3zP1P2.

I have this code in my category view:

```
<% collection.arrange.each do |category, sub_item| %>
  <a href="#<%= category.name %>" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="<%= category.root? ? '#MainMenu' : 'category.name' %>">
    <%= category.name %>
  </a>
  <div class="collapse" id="<%= category.name %>">
    <%# link_to category.name, category_path(category), class: 'list-group-item list-group-item-info', "data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-parent" => "#MainMenu" %>

    <% if category.has_children? %>
      <%= render partial: "category", locals: { collection: category.children } %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

These codes (`if category.has_children?`) are very expensive for the query. How to optimize? For every row in my menu I HAVE A QUERY!

Comment: You fail at explaining what your problem is exactly - please rephrase your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question should probably be closed, but at least the code it a bit more readable now.

Comment: I modify the question for better question. How to?